# Can audio files be used inline in HTML?

Tags: html, audio, mp3, base64url

Images can be used inline in websites using `<img src=”data:<MIMETYPE>;base64,<BASE64_ENCODED_IMAGE>”>`

Does this also work for audio files (e.g. mp3)?

Comment: Why would you want to do this?  Every day I see at least 5-10 posts about using data URIs and I have yet to see a single proper reason for doing so.  Almost always, it's folks not understanding how to properly handle blobs in JavaScript.  You realize that you're adding 33% overhead to the bandwidth requirements, as well as excess memory and CPU usage for zero benefit?

Comment: I am creating a single player, offline HTML5 card game - and if it comes just in one (HTML) file, it is easier to use

Comment: So now, you're subject to length limits and slowing everything down... again for no benefit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer yes

long answer

convert your audio file into base64 using either online or other form of tools

ex: `src="src="data:audio/ogg;base64,......." />`

here is a [live link](https://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php)