# How to play sound in javascript without external audio file/html file?

Tags: javascript

So im building something but im not allowed to use any external files other than the script.js file itself. I want to play a .mp3 sound in a function but im not sure how to do it without uploading the file into my folder.

Comment: How do you expect to play audio when there's no audio ? - do you have it's buffer ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can audio files be used inline in HTML?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61303710/can-audio-files-be-used-inline-in-html)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use javascript to set the audio data src to `data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAA+...` etc.

There's an example here. https://iandevlin.com/html5/data-uri/audio.php

To do this with javascript simply

```
var audioElement = new Audio();
audioElement.src = "data:audio/ogg;base64,T2dnUwACAAAAAAAAAAA+...";
audioElement.play();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your mp3 file using base64. Than you can the audio in a string:

```
var beep = "data:audio/mp3;base64,<paste your base64 here>";

var audio = document.getElementById('audio');
audio.src = beep;
audio.play();
```

The base64 string can be generate using a shell

`cat sound.mp3 | base64`